# Convert date and time

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a column with about 100 records in datetime (for example `2004-08-09 12:20:41:000`) and I would like to convert all records or update same time just date only with format `mm-dd-yyyy`.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the data type of the column?  If it is a datetime, then you will want to return the data in that format, not store it in a specific format.  Also what database are you using?

Comment: i can add another column for it, i'm using SQL 2008

Comment: Please add the schema of the table to your question.

Comment: just 2 column name and datetime

Comment: i can use date format yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: if TSQL use `CAST` or `CONVERT`, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: What is your database engine? What type is the column? What name does the column have? ...

Comment: using sql 2001 and the field name datecreate (datetime, not null)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting the datetime column as follows:

```
UPDATE [TableName]
    SET DateCreate = CAST(LEFT(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(25), DateCreate, 120), 10) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: it will reset time to 00:00:00 but not remove it and date format still yyy-mm-dd. can we remove the time and change date format to mm-dd-yyyy

Answer (score 1):

For `SQl Server 2008` you can use `convert` `function` like below.

```
--For output format mm-dd-yyyy
declare @d datetime = getdate() 
select convert(varchar(10), @d, 110)

--For output format yyyy-mm-dd
declare @d datetime = getdate() 
select convert(varchar(10), @d, 120)
```

If you are using `SQL Server 2012` and later, the new `format` function works fine too. Example below.

```
--For output format mm-dd-yyyy    
declare @d datetime = getdate()
select format(@d,'MM-dd-yyyy', 'en-US')

--For output format yyyy-mm-dd
declare @d datetime = getdate() 
select format(@d,'yyyy-MM-dd', 'en-US')
```

Comment: i have several table and not sure how to use this function to apply the right table

Comment: You can use the function in your select statement with each table where you have a datetime column you want to convert. Example: `select convert(varchar(10),mydatecolumn, 110) from mytable;` For update use update statement like, `update mytable set mydatecolumn = cast(convert(varchar(10),mydatecolumn, 110) as datetime);`

Comment: If you do not want the time component in your data table, you need to create a new column with `date` datatype and update data into that column.